# How to convert from "MM:SS.MS" to "SS.MS" in PHP?

Tags: php, milliseconds, seconds, minute

Please help to convert from "MM:SS.MS" to "SS.MS" in PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to solve that problem? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(new DateTime())->createFromFormat('G:s.u', '15:35.123')->format('s.u');
```

or just

```
explode(':', '15:23.123')[1];
```

Comment: Although you have a good intention by answering this off-topic question, be aware that it just encourages people to ask more such question because they get what they want.